# Problem in converting Java ArrayList with one element to JSON Object

Tags: java, web-services, json

I have developed  rest web service to get the JSON object list. When there is  more than one  objects rest web service return me correct JSON array.  But if there is only one object to return Rest web service not returning an JSON array. I want to get JSON  array for  all the time.

My rest service method

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/chekinList")
public List<LocationReguest> getChekinList(@QueryParam("childID") String userName, @QueryParam("appkey") String appkey, @QueryParam("appPassword") String appPassword) {
    LocationController locationController = new LocationController();
    List<LocationReguest> locreqlist = locationController.getChekinList(userName);
    //TODO return proper representation object
    return locreqlist;
}
```

> JSON Object return when having one object
>   {"childRequest":{"childName":"test123Child","childUserName":"add"}}
>
> JSON Object array  return when having more object
>
> {"childRequest":[{"childName":"Child
>   ONE","childUserName":"chlid1"},{"childName":"abayakoon","childUserName":"abey"}]}

Please help me to get solve this

Comment: What class/library are you using to convert to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://www.flittn.com/blog/?p=146 for a workaround

Comment: I have replaced the jettison 1.1  library by jettison 1.2 . But it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: The workaround is to use a custom `ContextResolver` as explained in the provided link